# Javascript: Validation script not working

Tags: php, javascript, validation

Ok, time to call in the experts:  Can anyone show me how to get this working correctly?!

**Background**: we have a PHP webform, clients have a drop-down field such as car type for example, they click on a value in that drop-down and a fieldset displays specific to that selection.  Clients could have required fields in all sections, but of course not all fieldsets are always displaying, so if the field does not have WxH, meaning it is not currently being displayed, so ignore the required/validation field flags, but if WxH > 0,  stop process, show error messages.

**Here's what's suppose to happen:**
json gathers all fields flagged as required:

```
[var fieldList = <?php echo "new Array(". trim(json_encode($reqFlds), '[]').")"; ?>;]
```

user clicks submit button
that json array is passed the function below, which should then determine if the width and height of the fields marked as required is/are >0
if >0 that means the field is currently being displayed on the screen, thus the form shouldn't be submitted until required field(s) are filled, msgs should appear.

Using FB, I see that it goes through the loop once, checks isVisible(), goes to "return blankFields;" and stops.
[image]

I will chalk this up to it being Friday, not sure how I missed adding the actual script.   Now I see why no one was responding:

```
function checkRequired(fieldList) {
    var field = null,
        blankFields = [],
        listText = [], listItem = [], fieldId = [], label = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < fieldList.length; i++) {
        listText = fieldList[i];
        listText = listText.substring(1, listText.length - 1);
        listItem = listText.split("||");
        fieldId = listItem[0];
        label = listItem[1];
        field = document.getElementById(fieldId);

        if (isVisible(field) && isBlank(field)) {
            blankFields.push(label);
        }
    return blankFields;
    }
function isVisible(field) {
    if (field.offsetWidth == 0 || field.offsetHeight == 0) return true;
}

function isBlank(field) {
    if ((field.type == "text" || field.type == "textarea") && field.value == "") return true;
    if (!(field.checked || field.selected || field.selectedIndex > -1)) return true;
    return false;
}

    if (blankFields.lentgh > 0 || blankFields.lentgh == 0) {
        displayError(blankFields);
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

function displayError(blankFields) {
    var Errmsg = "The must fill in the following fields in order to save your request:\n\n";
    for (var i = 0; i < blankFields.length; i++) {
        Errmsg += blankFields[i] + "\n";
                alert(Errmsg);
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**NOTE**:  It does not go back to the if statement that "blankdFields.push(lable);" after it does the isVisible function check

Comment: The function you're referencing is missing. That said....isn't there a better way to write your required fields function? Searching for fields that are currently displayed, by checking width and height, seems like a very rough solution...

Comment: I had a couple of ideas, but boss/programmer overruled, so I am trying to get her code working. Not sure where my function went. I am posting/reposting.

Comment: Ouch, man. I'm sorry, that's gotta really suck, since I feel that there are so many better solutions out there (enabling/disabling fieldsets, for one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be syntactical.

You have:

```
function checkRequired(fieldList) {
    var field = null,
        blankFields = [],
        listText = [], listItem = [], fieldId = [], label = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < fieldList.length; i++) {
        listText = fieldList[i];
        listText = listText.substring(1, listText.length - 1);
        listItem = listText.split("||");
        fieldId = listItem[0];
        label = listItem[1];
        field = document.getElementById(fieldId);

        if (isVisible(field) && isBlank(field)) {
            blankFields.push(label);
        }
    return blankFields;
    }
```

It looks as though you're missing a closing brace; you've messed up your scope a bit. Add a closing brace before the `return` statement. Because you don't have this brace, the function is aborting after the first loop because it encounters the `return` statement, which causes the function to stop execution and return `blankFields`.

What you want is this:

```
function checkRequired(fieldList) {
    var field = null,
        blankFields = [],
        listText = [], listItem = [], fieldId = [], label = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < fieldList.length; i++) {
        listText = fieldList[i];
        listText = listText.substring(1, listText.length - 1);
        listItem = listText.split("||");
        fieldId = listItem[0];
        label = listItem[1];
        field = document.getElementById(fieldId);

        if (isVisible(field) && isBlank(field)) {
            blankFields.push(label);
        }
    }

    return blankFields;
}
```

That should solve the immediate problem. Hope this helps.